# How to use Swift App + (Swift Framework + Objective C static Framework) without warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

**What I am trying to do:**

- Create a swift dynamic framework - Say SwiftDemo.framework
- Swift.framework depends upon an external Objective-C static framework
  (No source code available) - Say ObjCDemo.framework. This framework has
  it's module file and placed inside ObjCDemo.framework/Modules/module.modulemap
- Put this SwiftDemo.framework inside an Swift application. Ideally I would want my swift app to be able to use both SwiftDemo.framework and ObjCDemo.framework without any error or warning.

**What I have tried:**

- Create a swift dynamic framework SwiftDemo.framework
- Added ObjCDemo.framework in *"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"*. Put ObjCDemo.frameworks path in "Framework Search Paths" if not added automatically. Access ObjCDemo.framework using *"import ObjCDemo"*. Build the SwiftDemo.framework. It builds fine, No error, No warning
- Create a SwiftDemo application.
- Add SwiftDemo.framework in *"Embedded Binaries"* section.

Try to build SwiftDemo.app, below is the error:

> ld: framework not found ObjCDemo for architecture x86_64

Obviously SwiftDemo.app not able to find the ObjCDemo.framework which is used by SwiftDemo.framework, So next I did:

- Added ObjCDemo.framework in *"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"* and accordingly set the *"Frameworks Search Paths"* of SwiftDemo.app target

Try to build SwiftDemo.app, No error but this is the console warning I get for every file in ObjCDemo.framework:

> objc[15127]: Class  is implemented in both /Users/tarun/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4391A259-64DF-4893-BE09-31B5D2D5BC8C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CD896A7B-1868-44D1-BFEA-6CC081AD41DB/SwiftDemo.app/Frameworks/SwiftDemo.framework/Swift and /Users/tarun/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4391A259-64DF-4893-BE09-31B5D2D5BC8C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CD896A7B-1868-44D1-BFEA-6CC081AD41DB/SwiftDemo.app/SwiftDemo. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Obviously these files are duplicated in both SwiftDemo.framework and SwiftDemo.app, So to avoid next I did:

- Remove ObjCDemo.framework form *"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"* of
  SwiftDemo.app target but keep *"Frameworks Search Paths"* still
  pointing to ObjCDemo.framework path.

Try to build SwiftDemo.app, No error but this is the compile time warning:

> ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '.../SwiftDemo/ObjCDemo.framework/ObjCDemo', framework linker option at ..../SwiftDemo/ObjCDemo.framework/ObjCDemo is not a dylib

No matter what I just couldn't get pass these errors or warnings. Anyone got any solution to this?

Comment: Having a similar problem. Would be great to get an answer.

Comment: I have asked my question separately as it has the same warnings, but slightly different setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544257/error-in-linking-of-a-static-ios-framework-to-both-apps-and-xctest-targets.