# Error in linking of a static iOS framework to both app's and XCTest targets

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks

I have an app which has Objective-C and Swift combined. It has an XCTest target. I have a static framework written in Objective-C which is linked to a main target and is used by main target and test target.

I have tested 3 different cases, in which two of them compile but with warnings, while I want to see no warnings when I run my tests:

1) Static framework is not linked to test target (via `Link Binary With Libraries`), but is included to the test target's `Framework search paths`. The test target compiles but I have warning:

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '.../MyStaticFramework/MyStaticFramework.framework/MyStaticFramework', framework linker option at /.../MyStaticFramework/MyStaticFramework.framework/MyStaticFramework is not a dylib
```

2) Static framework is linked to test target (via `Link Binary With Libraries`), and is included to the test target's `Framework search paths`. The test target compiles but I have warning:

```
objc[2653]: Class MyStaticFrameworkClassA is implemented in both /.../MyApp.app/MyApp and /.../MyApp.app/PlugIns/Tests.xctest/Tests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

3) Static framework is not linked to test target (via `Link Binary With Libraries`), and is not included to the test target's `Framework search paths`. The test target does not compile:

```
In file included from ".../Tests/.../TestFile.m:13:
.../Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.build/../MyApp.build/DerivedSources/MyApp-Swift.h:103:9: fatal error: module 'MyStaticFramework' not found
@import MyStaticFramework;
 ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: This issue has slightly different setup but the developer has the same warnings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532190/how-to-use-swift-app-swift-framework-objective-c-static-framework-without.